# Layout looks bad even though constraints are added

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I designed something on table view cell and then i clicked "Add missing constraints"

it looks like this

[image]

But when i run it on iphone 5s simulator, it looks like this

[image]

It doesn't fit the layout and overflows

How can i make it looks fit on all iphone 4-5-6 ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of all the constraints, too?

Comment: You will need to choose a set of constraints that allow the labels in the middle to shrink. The image on the left should be pinned to the left of the contentView; the two tables and the stars should be pinned to the right of the contentView (or the stars pinned the right and the labels left aligned to the stars). The labels in the middle should shrink; You may need to alter the content compression priority on the labels. Please provide more info on your constraints.

Comment: i usually select all elements and click "Add missing constraints"

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not know how to set up constraints that will cause a UI to "look good". Looking good is a subjective human judgment and computers can't do that.

"Add Missing Constraints" will just make some rough guesses, as best as the Xcode engineers were able to generate algorithmically. They are guaranteed to be sufficient to resolve ambiguities in the current set of constraints, but not guaranteed to do anything especially smart for keeping a UI looking good.

Auto layout requires you, the developer, to do thoughtful, careful consideration of how the UI should look under various circumstances. You then have to set up the constraints to achieve that. You can't just go on autopilot. You have to do the work.

If, after setting up the constraints, you still get results which are wrong, you need to show the specific constraints you set up, how you expected the UI to be laid out in various circumstances, what behavior you actually got, and how that differs from what you wanted/expected.

For example, you say about the screenshots, "it doesn't fit" and "[it] overflows". Well, which elements of your UI would you want to have moved and/or resized, and how, to get it to fit and not overflow? Do you want the image to be made smaller? Do you want the "Feedback" and "Download" buttons and the stars to get closer together? Would you want any of those to be truncated or clipped if the overall width is just too narrow to fit all of them? Etc.